my selenium code doesn;t want to link with the webdriver
I tried to teach myself how to code with selenium but it did not work no matter what i tried.
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

service = Service(executable_path="C:\Users\USER.PC-20220517DPKY\Desktop\coding\bot\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

# jetzt starten wir das programm
driver.get('https://google.com')

#jetzt targeten wir eine css class im html text 
input_element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_Name,'gLFyf')
input_element.send_keys('bals')
time.sleep(10)

#ende des programs
driver.quit()

I installed the webdriver like described in this video by tech with tim: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NB8OceGZGjA
I installed selenium which was successful and i put the cromedriver in the same folder as the code file. The current version of my google chrome is Version 125.0.6422.142 but the webdriver is only available in 125.0.6422.141 . I tried asking Copilot but it didn't really gave me an answer...
This is the error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 97, in start
path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(browser)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/selenium_manager.py", line 75, in driver_location
str(self.get_binary()),
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/selenium_manager.py", line 56, in get_binary
raise SeleniumManagerException(f"{path} is missing.  Please open an issue on {tracker}")
selenium.common.exceptions.SeleniumManagerException: Message: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/linux/selenium-manager is missing.  Please open an issue on https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/lulatsch3841/github/my_projects/bot/main.py", line 7, in 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 80, in init
super().init(
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 101, in init
self.service.start()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 100, in start
raise err
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 90, in start
self._start_process(self.path)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 218, in _start_process
raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home

Please could you add the error message you're receiving to the question?

@StephenGraham I just updated the error message

It is difficult to answer without the specific error message.
It looks like there are a couple of issues. First of all try not specifying the executable path for chrome. This should use ensure the version of chrome matches the chromedriver.
Secondly, By.CLASS_Name is not correct. You need to use By.CLASS_NAME
Thirdly, when you open google in selenium, it will most likely display a cookie popup that you need to dismiss. Otherwise, trying to enter text in the searchbar will fail. For me this is handled with the following code:
reject_all = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'W0wltc')
reject_all.click()

This is the ID of the 'reject all' cookie button. You might need to use a different ID in your code.
Altogether the working code should look like this:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.google.com")

# Dismiss the cookies popup
reject_all = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'W0wltc')
reject_all.click()

input_element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'gLFyf')
input_element.send_keys('bals')
time.sleep(10)


driver.quit()

